# How to join array with comma per 3 items in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array ( [0] => '2' [1] => '3' [2] => '4' [3] => '5' [4] => '6' [5] => '7' )
```

I want to join them per 3 items like below

```
Array ( [0] => '2,3,4' [1] => '5,6,7' )
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split the array into blocks of 3 entries, then [array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a callback that uses [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join that block of three elements into one string with comma separators.

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($value) {
        return implode(',', $value);
    },
    array_chunk($myArray, 3)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
// Array definition
$array = array(0 => '2', 1 => '3', 2 => '4', 3 => '5', 4 => '6', 5 => '7');

// New array: [ 0 => [2, 3, 4], 1 => [5, 6, 7] ]
$resultArray = array_chunk($array, 3);

// Join the elements with comma
foreach($resultArray as &$row){
    $row = implode(',', $row);
}
```